# What happens to not displayed votes after reputation gain?

Tags: support

I have voted on quite a lot of questions, but I currently have 10 reputation, so the votes aren't public.
I wonder if these votes get "public" after getting the vote-privilege.

Comment: Wait, how can you vote if you have no [privilege to vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: @tushar the buttons are enabled for all users, they just don't affect the posts score until you have the up and down vote privileges. The data is collected by SE, but they don't do anything eith it (yet)

Comment: @Turamarth that's what I was looking for - thanks!